# Design Of Sign In Screen

Tags: android

[image]

I have a problem with the Login Page. Don't know to arrange views as I am posting the code that I tried both in Mobile and Tab.
Thanks in advance.
Any help will be appreciated.

Below I am posting the code of Layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/activity_sign_in_back">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottomLayout">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/activity_sign_in_logo" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ivLogo"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_unfocus_background"
                    android:padding="15dp" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_unfocus_background"
                    android:padding="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llRemember"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/tvNoAccount"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
                    android:visibility="invisible"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCheckBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:src="@drawable/activity_check_box_remember_me" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRememberView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity=""
                        android:text="@string/text_message_remember_me"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSignIn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/llRemember"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/view_white_border"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_message_sign_in"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_large_size"
                    android:onClick="signIn"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvForgotPassword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSignIn"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_message_forgot_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_large_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlBottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNoAccount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/text_message_no_account"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSignUp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tvNoAccount"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        [enter image description here][1]android:background="@drawable/view_white_background"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/text_message_sign_up"
                        android:onClick="signUpActivity"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have attached the images one is real and other that I made. I tried  to make the image as real but unable to succeed. If anyone have some idea that how to make this then please help me. I am actually trying this from last 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#acacac">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/lin_bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Dont have account?"/>

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Signup Now"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_above="@id/lin_bottom"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="UserNAme"/>

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint= "password"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Remember Me"/>

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Sign In" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Forgot Password?"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>
```

Updated Please check

Comment: I have to scroll the screen because  some screens are small some are big.

Comment: @Shobin Kumar Yes you have to add your layout in scrollview

Comment: No...It is not...@VjLxmi